# notify the user when he receives new message on WEB application

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket, ajax-polling

Recently I started working on web applications. Sorry if this is silly question.

I had an Android app earlier. I was using GCM for push notifications. Recently I have developed a web app using PHP for this application. I should notify the user when he receives new messages,alerts etc..

I read many blogs and learned that using **WebSockets** is the good solution.

So my question is

1. Is using Websockets a good solution ? Do I have any other good alternative?
2. How to use WebSockets here? **Do I need to send request to Apache server for every interval after user login** ? If yes what is the recommended value for interval? (please help me with sample example if possible)
3. Can I use WebSockets in shared hosting?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.